# NamedPipe vs TCP/IP in little data

Tags: c#, .net, tcp, named-pipes

Hi
Is It true that if we pass little data back and forth to client/server the overhead of tcp/ip is negligible and performance is the same as NamedPipe on the same machine ?

Comment: I'd say this depends on architecture so you better measure yourself in your specific conditions.

Comment: Performance is very subjective to what you are trying to accomplish. Number of transactions in X amount of time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd say it's not so much the *quantity of data* as much as it is the *number of requests*.  In other words, if you have 100,000 connections that pass 100 bytes of data, you're going to have more tcp/ip overhead than if you have 10 connections of 100K each.

That's not to say that there isn't overhead associated with transferring the data via tcp/ip vs. named pipes.  There is.  But usually I'd say the decision of which one you're going to use has to do more with the architecture of your system than concern about the overhead.

If you're going to transfer data between physical servers, you have to go with tcp/ip; named pipes aren't an option.  If you're transferring data between processes on the same server, named pipes are clearly the better performer.

One reason you might want to go with tcp/ip when you're on the same physical server is if there's a chance that you'll break the processes onto physical servers at some point in the future.

To answer your question:  If you're not passing a lot of data, and you're not doing it frequently, you're probably not going to notice the tcp/ip overhead when the two endpoints are on the same physical machine.

HTH,
James